# Prolog: Reverse function of string_to_list

Tags: prolog

I know the Prolog-builtin "string_to_list". Now i need to reverse its functionality.

```
?- string_to_list('a*1+2', L).
L = [97, 42, 49, 43, 50].
```

How can i reverse this? Is there a builtin function?
Anything that does what "desiredfunction" does, would be a great help.

```
?- desiredfunction([97, 42, 49, 43, 50], R).
R = 'a*1+2'.
```

Thank you.

Comment: @false I started with `atom_codes/2` because OP is passing an atom for the first parameter, but edited to `string_codes/2` when I realized that OP used `string_to_list/2`. Do you think `atom_codes/2` is more appropriate?

Answer (score 4):

`string_to_list/2` is deprecated in favor of [`string_codes/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=string_codes/2).

The predicate is *bidirectional*, meaning that you can plug in a list, and get a string back on the other side.

```
string_codes(R, [97, 42, 49, 43, 50])
```

Better yet, use [`atom_codes/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atom_codes/2), which is also bidirectional, and is more widely supported among Prolog implementations:

```
atom_codes(R, [97, 42, 49, 43, 50])
```

[This produces](http://ideone.com/zTDjRx)

```
a*1+2
```

Comment: @false Thanks, `writeq` definitely makes more sense. I forgot that it even existed (last time I wrote Prolog for work was 22 years ago).